# React const cannot call 2 different attributes?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm a little new to react and was trying to make a responsive navbar with popup modals as a little project, however as I've tried to call the const twice in App.js with its different attributes, only one of it was working in the app. 
I've tried removing the working one and the other works fine, the only problem it them working together.

Toolbar.js

```
import React from 'react';
import Logo from "../../img/DW_Logo.png";
import DrawerToggleButton from '../SideDrawer/DrawerToggleButton';
import './Toolbar.css';


const toolbar = props => (
<header className="toolbar">
    <nav className="toolbar_navigation">

        <div className="toolbar_logo">
            <a href="/"><img src={Logo} /></a>
        </div>
        <div className="spacer" />
        <div className="toolbar_navigation-items">
            <ul>
                <li><a href="/">About</a></li>
                <li><a onClick={props.popup}>News</a></li>
                <li className="sign_in"><a href="/">Sign In/ Login</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
        <div className="toolbar_toggle">
            <DrawerToggleButton click={props.drawerClickHandler} />
        </div>
    </nav>
</header>

);

export default toolbar;
```

as you can see i have `onClick={props.popup}` as well as `click={props.drawerClickHandler}`

Which I try to run in App.js

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import Toolbar from './header/Toolbar/Toolbar';
import SideDrawer from './header/SideDrawer/SideDrawer';
import Backdrop from './header/Backdrop/Backdrop';
import Modal from "./header/Modal/Modal";

class App extends Component {

  state = {
    sideDrawerOpen: false
  };
  state = {
    modalOpen: false
  };
  drawerToggleClickHandler = () => {
    this.setState((prevState) => {
      return {sideDrawerOpen: !prevState.sideDrawerOpen};
    });
  };

  modalClickHandler = () => {
    this.setState((prevState) => {
      return {modalOpen: !prevState.modalOpen};
    });
  };

  backdropClickHandler = () => {
    this.setState({sideDrawerOpen: false});
    this.setState({modalOpen: false});
  };

  render() {
    let backdrop;

    if (this.state.sideDrawerOpen) {
      backdrop = <Backdrop click={this.backdropClickHandler} />;
    }
    if (this.state.modalOpen) {
      backdrop = <Backdrop click={this.backdropClickHandler} />;
    }
    return (
      <div style={{height: '100%'}}>
        <Toolbar drawerClickHandler={this.drawerToggleClickHandler} />
        <Toolbar popup={this.modalClickHandler} />
        <SideDrawer show={this.state.sideDrawerOpen} />
        {backdrop}
        <Modal show={this.state.modalOpen}/>

        <main style={{marginTop: '64px'}}>
          <p>This is the page content!</p>
        </main> 
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

Only `<Toolbar popup={this.modalClickHandler} />` was running, and if i remove it, `<Toolbar drawerClickHandler={this.drawerToggleClickHandler} />` works just fine.

I'm building this modal based on the side drawer I've learned from a tutorial, and came to this roadblock which I need help understanding and also resolving.

Comment: Try passing both click handlers to both components. Have you checked the error logs? Is there anything showing an error?

Comment: There was no error displayed, but putting them together seems to do the trick, I'm guessing the latter component had overridden the previous call so it didn't work when I called it twice individually. Thanks!

Comment: No problem. You were most likely getting a missing prop error. Since you were setting both click functions specifically in the component it expects to receive both even if only one is being used.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think that this isn't const problem..,

`<Toolbar drawerClickHandler={this.drawerToggleClickHandler} popup={this.modalClickHandler} />`

you should add one component two props..

```
return (
  <div style={{height: '100%'}}>
    <Toolbar drawerClickHandler={this.drawerToggleClickHandler} 
             popup={this.modalClickHandler}/>
    <SideDrawer show={this.state.sideDrawerOpen} />
    {backdrop}
    <Modal show={this.state.modalOpen}/>

    <main style={{marginTop: '64px'}}>
      <p>This is the page content!</p>
    </main> 
  </div>
);
```

Answer (score 0):

Seem like you design toolbar to use both drawerClickHandler prop and popup props together in one components.

But you render toolbar component 2 times and pass separate drawerClickHandler props and popup props to them.

I think you should render toolbar only one time and pass both drawerClickHandler props and popup props.

EXAMPLE:

```
render () {
  return (
    <div style={{height: '100%'}}>
     <Toolbar drawerClickHandler={this.drawerToggleClickHandler} popup={this.modalClickHandler} />
     <SideDrawer show={this.state.sideDrawerOpen} />
     {backdrop}
     <Modal show={this.state.modalOpen}/>

    <main style={{marginTop: '64px'}}>
      <p>This is the page content!</p>
    </main> 
   </div>
  )
}
```